# New to Python: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python

I am new to Python, the first project that assigned to and needs to support now :) Python seems to be super friendly language.   So forgive me for dumb questions.

I am getting the following error:

```
  File "AlKamelClient.py", line 316, in <module>
    client.main()
  File "AlKamelClient.py", line 296, in main
    self.dispatch_reply_message(self.parse_msg(msg))
  File "AlKamelClient.py", line 226, in dispatch_reply_message
    self.log_to_db(message)
  File "AlKamelClient.py", line 181, in log_to_db
    if 'session' in data['timing']:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Line 181 is "if 'session' in data['timing']:" in the code below.

I have seen using a try: catching the exception etc.   I am not sure where to go from here.

Code is:

```
def log_to_db(self, message):

    channel = message['channel']
    data = message['data']

    if 'timing' in data:
        if 'session' in data['timing']:
            if 'info' in data['timing']['session']:
                pp.pprint(data['timing']['session']['info'])
                self._timing_session_info.update(data['timing']['session']['info'])
                self._session_id = db.timing_session_info(self._db.cursor(), db.NoneDict(self._timing_session_info))

            if 'entry' in data['timing']['session']:
                pp.pprint(data['timing']['session']['entry'])
                db.timing_session_entry(self._db.cursor(), db.NoneDict(data['timing']['session']['entry']), self._session_id)

            if 'flags' in data['timing']['session']:
                pp.pprint(data['timing']['session']['flags'])
                db.timing_session_flags(self._db.cursor(), db.NoneDict(data['timing']['session']['flags']), self._session_id)

        if 'liveEvents' in data['timing']:
            if 'fl' in data['timing']['liveEvents']:
                pp.pprint(data['timing']['liveEvents']['fl'])
                db.timing_liveEvents_fl(self._db.cursor(), data['timing']['liveEvents']['fl'], self._session_id)
            if 'sector' in data['timing']['liveEvents']:
                pp.pprint(data['timing']['liveEvents']['sector'])
                db.timing_liveEvents_sector(self._db.cursor(), db.NoneDict(data['timing']['liveEvents']['sector']), self._session_id)

    if 'telemEvent' in data:
        pp.pprint(data['telemEvent'])
        db.telemEvent(self._db.cursor(), db.NoneDict(data['telemEvent']), self._session_id)
```

Comment: The problem is with your `data` varibale which is apperantly `None`. What is the type of `message` argument?

Comment: Rather, `data['timing']` is `None`.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the correction. Also I would that `if` structure to `try/except`. more pythonic

Comment: You could instead test like this: `if data['timing'] and 'session' in data['timing']:`. This still assumes you tested `'timing' in data` on the previous line.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that `data['timing']` is not set i.e. set to null/None.

the statement:

```py
if 'session' in data['timing']:
```

actually iterates over `data['timing']` but since it is null/None it can not iterate over it. You should put a check if it is actually set.